# Error with Employee class creation in C#

Tags: c#, class, listbox

I have written this program in C# for an assignment I have due tonight. What I have to do is create a class named "Employee" have have the information display on a List Box. I believe that I have everything together, and I am not showing any syntax errors, but when I attempt to run the program, nothing happens. Do you think you can help me find out why its not working? All that appears is a blank list box. Here is my code on my Form1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Adam_Zeidan___IS_204___HW10CH9_4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("Name\t\tID Number\tDepartment\tPosition");

            Employee emp1 = emp1 = new Employee();
            emp1.Name = "Susan Meyers";
            emp1.IdNumber = 47899;
            emp1.Department = "Accounting";
            emp1.Position = "Vice President";
            listBox1.Items.Add(emp1.Name + "\t" + emp1.IdNumber + "\t\t" +     emp1.Department + "\t" + emp1.Position);

            Employee emp2 = emp2 = new Employee();
            emp2.Name = "Mark Jones";
            emp2.IdNumber = 39119;
            emp2.Department = "IT";
            emp2.Position = "Programmer";
            listBox1.Items.Add(emp2.Name + "\t" + emp2.IdNumber + "\t\t" +     emp2.Department + "\t" + emp2.Position);

            Employee emp3 = emp3 = new Employee();
            emp3.Name = "Joy Rogers";
            emp3.IdNumber = 81774;
            emp3.Department = "Manufacturing";
            emp3.Position = "Engineer";
            listBox1.Items.Add(emp3.Name + "\t" + emp3.IdNumber + "\t\t" +     emp3.Department + "\t" + emp3.Position);

        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs     e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Now this is the Employee.cs code that I used to create the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Adam_Zeidan___IS_204___HW10CH9_4
{
    class Employee
    {
        private string _name;
        private int _idNumber;
        private string _department;
        private string _position;

        public Employee()
        {
            _name = "";
            _idNumber = 0;
            _department = "";
            _position = "";
        }

        public Employee(string name, int idNumber)
        {
            _name = name;
            _idNumber = idNumber;
            _department = "";
            _position = "";
        }

        public Employee(string name, int idNumber, string department, string     position)
        {
            _name = name;
            _idNumber = idNumber;
            _department = department;
            _position = position;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
            }
        }

        public int IdNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return _idNumber;
            }
            set
            {
                _idNumber = value;
            }
        }

        public string Department
        {
            get
            {
                return _department;
            }
            set
            {
                _department = value;
            }
        }

    public string Position
    {
        get
        {
            return _position;
        }
        set
        {
            _position = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Do you think you can help me find out why its not working?

Comment: Can you try adding a ToString() to your IdNumber when adding it to the list box? e.g. emp1.IdNumber.ToString()

Comment: The form load function probably isn't registered.  Put a break point in the load function and see if you get there.  Click on a line in the code and press F9.  Then stop program and restart.

Comment: What is the point of `Employee emp1 = emp1 = new Employee();`? Why not just `Employee emp1 = new Employee();`?

Comment: I can't add a ToString because when I do, a syntax error shows up and says that it is a method group.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, JRLambert, I didnt notice it before. unfortunetly, though, it did not fix my problem.

Comment: how would i go about putting a break point in the load function, jdweng?

Comment: Try this then: string lbItem1 = string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t\t{2}\t{3}", emp1.Name, emp1.IdNumber, emp1.Department, emp1.Position);
listBox1.Items.Add(lbItem1);

Answer (score 1):

Change the following lines

```
Employee emp1 = emp1 = new Employee();
Employee emp2 = emp2 = new Employee();
Employee emp3 = emp3 = new Employee();
```

to

```
 Employee emp1 = new Employee();
 Employee emp2 = new Employee();
 Employee emp3 = new Employee();
```

Comment: I have changed them to the way that you have described, but it still has not solved my issue. thank you though.

Comment: then can you please make sure your load event is binded with the your form?

because it's working for me. click on  the first line under Form1_Load()
and press F9. Run the project and see if compiler comes here

Comment: I pressed F9 on the InitializeComponent(); line under Form1_Load() and ran the program. the line is now highlighted in yellow.

Comment: so it comes in your form1_load then i wonder what would be the problem.

Comment: Download the working copy form here
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fggvlqmqd8ta8ao/WindowsFormsApplication1.zip?dl=0

Comment: Thank you so much Nouman. I just have one more concern. How can i resize the listbox in your version of the program? I can resize it in the designer view, but it does not change when I run the program.

Comment: I think there's something wrong with your Visual Studio, because I can do it easily in my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the given snippet; that works fine for me, please check the properties of the `ListBox` for it's visibility and also make sure that the `Form1_Load` event is firing. I have a suggestion to simplify your code by `overriding .ToString()` in the class in the following way:

```
public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Name + "\t" + this.IdNumber + "\t\t" + this.Department + "\t" + this.Position;
    }
```

So that the code in the `Form1_Load` will be as like the following:

```
  Employee emp1 = new Employee();
  emp1.Name = "Susan Meyers";
  emp1.IdNumber = 47899;
  emp1.Department = "Accounting";
  emp1.Position = "Vice President";
  listBox1.Items.Add(emp1.ToString());
  Employee emp2 = new Employee();
  //init emp2 here
  listBox1.Items.Add(emp2.ToString());
  Employee emp3 = emp3 = new Employee();
  //init emp3 here
  listBox1.Items.Add(emp3.ToString());
```